# read text in file

Tags: java, user-interface

how to read and print the content in text file ?

can i just call the `readFile()` method in `showInputDialog()`?
for example:

```
  String q = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 
                       "what is your name", 
                       "Get Name   Demo",
                       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
                       null, 
                       null, 
                       readText());

private String readText()throws Exception{
    BufferedReader reader = null; 

       reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/name.txt")); 
            String name = reader.readLine();  
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(name, " ");
            String NAME= st.nextElement().toString();

           if(reader!=null) 
           reader.close();             

        return NAME;
    }
```

ERROR:
Unreported exception java.lang.Exception;must be caught or declared be thrown

Answer (score 0):

Your `readText` method throws a checked Exception which you need to control.

You can use a `try-catch` block for it or add a `throws` clause in your method that uses your `readText` method.

Do like this:

```
try{
String q = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 
                       "what is your name", 
                       "Get Name   Demo",
                       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
                       null, 
                       null, 
                       readText());
}catch(Exception e){
//do the stuff that you want to do if there was some prblem reading your file
}
```

Or add a `throws Exception` clause to the method that encloses that above `String q = ....` part of your code.

One more thing you might like to do is have a `try-catch` block inside your `readText` method and store the contents read from the file in a string and  inside the catch block make a string that contains some message like `Unable to read file` and return that string from your method.

```
private String readText(){
// Note that I have removed that throws Exception from above
BufferedReader reader = null;
String myText=""; 
try{
       reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/name.txt")); 
       String name = reader.readLine();  
       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(name, " ");
       String NAME= st.nextElement().toString();
       myText = NAME;            
}catch(Exception e){
       myText = "Unable to read file";//or any message you want to convey

}finally{
       if(reader != null){
             try{
             reader.close();
             }catch(Exception e){
             }
       }
}
return myText;

}
```

Comment: i have tried to put try-catch block in readFile() method and the method had been called. bu still cannot get the output correctly. when i try to assign the variable like 'String myText = "aaaaaa" ', its print out 'aaaaaa'.

Comment: do you mean that the string `myText` is not populated with the contents of the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to handle the exceptions in called method so avoid throwing like this

```
private String readText(){


    BufferedReader reader = null; 
    String NAME ="";

    try
    {

           reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/name.txt")); 
           String name = reader.readLine();  
           StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(name, " ");
           NAME= st.nextElement().toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
         if(reader!=null) 
               reader.close();  
    return NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. now the problem is after adding the try-catch block, can compile the button doesnt work

Comment: ok print stacktrace and show what it says.I think it is due to the fileNotFoundException.

Comment: check the edited answer check now and show the Exception trace if it comes.

Comment: If there's an exception, the calling method will need different logic because it's depending on the value read from the file. It would be easier to throw the IOException.

Comment: thanks. its works after i h chngd the file name. thanks alot guys!